# How to draw 2/5 of circle

Tags: android, drawable

My current code like below:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#E6EDFB" />
    <size
        android:width="@dimen/_88sdp"
        android:height="@dimen/_44sdp" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_44sdp"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_44sdp" />
</shape>
```

It draws a half of circle:
[image].
But I want to draw just 2/5 of a circle like this:
[image].
How can I do this?

Comment: you  can try a small trick of drawing another rectangle at the bottom and clip it with the circle to get the desired effect

Comment: Will it make a blank area at the bottom?

Comment: if you use the same color as the background then it will give an illusion of shorter semi circle. or you can use various clipping methods available in porter duff class to clip the two views

Comment: You could try creating a custom view instead and draw a closed path arc in the onDraw method.